# Multiple Shared Datasets on the same form SQL Server 2012

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services

I am doing a sum in a `iif` condition

```
 =sum(Iif(Fields!Status.Value ="yes",1,0),"dtsTemp")
```

It works fine, but when I add another shared dataset and add a field to the same report

```
=sum(Iif(Fields!Status.Value ="yes",1,0),"dtsTemp2")
```

it doesn't work. When I go to Expression -> `Fields!Status.Value` (is underlined) seems it doesn't recognize the field. How do I make it work with multiple shared datasets?

Thanks,

Comment: Is "Status" a valid field in dtTemp2 dataset. Also make sure the field names and dataset name are in correct case as ssrs is case sensitive.

Comment: It's not just a typo is it and **dtTemp2** is supposed to be **dtsTemp2**

Comment: sorry I made a typo when writing the post. I checked the spelling, everything is correct.

Comment: What are the two fields? Are they just two text boxes added to the body of the report with no lists, tables etc underneath them?

Comment: the two fields are coming from two different views database. I created two separate Shared Datasets each Dataset has its own view. Then I added the two datasets to the report and trying to get the sum for each field.